# Restsharp Patch request

Tags: c#, for-loop, restsharp

I am using restsharp client. Trying to create patch request and update a couple of fields. This is my first experience working with restsharp. I am getting json parser error(The JSON patch document was malformed and could not be parsed).

I am able to do POST request without any issues.

Here is my code:

```
var client = new RestClient(RequestProperties.ClientUrl + @"Jobs?id=" + jobs.JobAccessId.ToString());    
var token = RequestProperties.Token;

client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));

var request = new RestRequest(Method.PATCH) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", token);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json-patch+json");
request.AddJsonBody(new { op = "replace", path = "/shippedDate", value = jobs.ShippedDate });
request.AddJsonBody(new { op = "replace", path = "/statusdCode", value = jobs.StatusdCode.ToString() });

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: so you want to send this json file as body and send it, is that correct ? Also can you paste here as json what you need to send ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with this code:

1. It is preferred to keep a single instance of the `RestClient` for one base URL. The base URL should not include any parameter values.
2. We advise using `AddQueryParameter` to specify query parameters per request.
3. You better use the JWT authorizer to give requests the bearer token rather than adding the header manually. It is also done on the client level.
4. When using `AddJsonBody`, there's no need to add content type and request data type, it is all done automatically.
5. Probably most importantly, you can only have *one* body parameter for any kind of request. It is not a RestSharp limitation, that's how HTTP works.